# C# AWS serverless application and CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, cors, serverless

We're using dotnet to create an AWS serverless application which use API keys.  However, we're running into CORS issues because all OPTIONS calls into the service also require the x-api-key...  I've tried enabling CORS in the AWS API Gateway but it errors out and I've also tried manually doing it.  Neither works.  Oh, and I have also added the CORS stuff to the Startup.cs of the serverless code and it still requires the x-api-key for the OPTIONS method...

Anyone have any ideas?  When javascript tries to call my serverless app it hits the same resource (api/mapper/GetKeys for example) but instead of sending GET sends OPTIONS.  Is there some way to capture all OPTIONS methods and return the correct CORS stuff without requiring the x-api-key header?

Comment: Does this forum post help you? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=658072#658072

Comment: That might have done it!  My google-fu must be weak!